# Why is this ExtJS combo box not filtering?

Tags: javascript, geoext, ext-js

I am trying to place a combo-box in the top of my web application which will search an internal WFS from Geoserver. I am using the combo-box so I can have the "type ahead" functionality which I think will help then narrow down the site they are looking for. Then once I solve this issue I will have a listener which will get the info and zoom to the location on selection.

I am working of a test at then moment to see if I can implement it in an existing site, but I am running into some trouble. The combo-box doesn't filter the data store, it just returns a full list of the datastore regardless of what i type (see picture at bottom of post).

The code I have used is below, unfortunately I don't have an external facing site to show.

I originally was hoping to set my WFS output format to JSON and just load that into a JSON data store but I kept getting errors that I was unable to decipher.

Thanks

Ando

```
var queryLayer = "dam";
var protocol= OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: "/geoserver/ows",
    featureType: queryLayer,
    featureNS: "www.awebsite.com.au", //Just for SE proper featureNS website used in application
    version: "1.0.0",
    srsName: "EPSG:4283"
});

var assetStore = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    fields: [
        {name: "name", type: "string"}
        //{name: "type", type: "string"}
    ],
    proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
            protocol: protocol              
        })
     });

new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: "border",
    items: [{
        region: "center",
        id: "mappanel",
        //title: "Map",
        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
        map: map,
        tbar:['->',{
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'Search for an asset:',
                store: assetStore,
                displayField: 'name',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                minChars: 1,
                displayField: 'name'                                                            
        }],
        layers: [layer],
        extent: extent,
        split: true
    }]
});
```

[image]

*Edit* This is the query that is getting sent to the server, its not passing the name from the combo box to the query so I assume that why everything is being returned. Is there a configOption I am missing here??

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><wfs:Query typeName="feature:dam" xmlns:feature="www.mywebsite.com.au"/></wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: Since this is more of an ExtJS question, you might have better luck with it on http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem today!
Remove the

```
 triggerAction: 'all',
```

option and it will work.
*triggerAction* in fact tells the combox to always display all of its values regardless of filters.

Documentation is scarce, but this thread describes the possible values for triggerAction:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?40428-combo-box-triggerAction

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no luck unfortunately. I attached to my original post the request getting sent to the server, and it appears that the name in the combo box is not being included in the <wfs:query> request. Not to sure why, been googling with no avail - I may ditch the combo box and just have a text field search.

Answer (score 1):

In your combobox you only appeaar to be setting a displayField and not a valueField - the actual value that is selected when an item is selected. Try:

```
   {
            xtype: 'combo',
            fieldLabel: 'Search for an asset:',
            store: assetStore,
            displayField: 'name',
            forceSelection: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            minChars: 1,
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name'                                                      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem caused by running clearFilter on the store e.g:
assetStore.clearFilter();

Remove this from your code, it's not needed in ext4.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the combo box config:

```
mode:"local"
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

You should try that config option:

```
typeAhead: true
```

See: [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-typeAhead)

Comment: I put that configuration option in, same results.